# onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse is not triggering in flutter local notifications

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-packages

This is my void main function:

```
Future<void> remoteMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(remoteMessageHandler);
  LocalNotificationService.initialize();
  NotificationSettings settings =
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

and this is my local notification service:

```
class LocalNotificationService {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static void onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse(
      NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
    print('background');
  }

  static Future<void> initialize() async {
    // initializationSettings  for Android
    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher"),
    );
    // Create the default notification channel here
    const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'default_notification_channel_id',
      'Default Notification Channel',
      importance: Importance.max,
    );

    _notificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    await _notificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse:
          onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse response) async {
        print('normal');
      },
    );
  }

  static void createanddisplaynotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    try {
      final id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
      const NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          "pushnotificationapp",
          "pushnotificationappchannel",
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
        ),
      );

      await _notificationsPlugin.show(
        id,
        message.notification!.title,
        message.notification!.body,
        notificationDetails,
        payload: message.data['_id'],
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I asked chatgpt, bard and etc but all are saying call onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse and it will work.And most people says to use onselectnotificaiotn instead of onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse but I don't have parameter onselectnotificaiotn.

Comment: @AradhyaBasek any solutions ? have the same issue, only onDidReceiveNotificationResponse will trigger when I open the app from notification.

Comment: No man I can't find any solutoins!

Comment: Same issue here! I've been stuck for hours without a solution :(

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me. Update AppDelegate.swift to this code:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import flutter_local_notifications

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    // This is required to make any communication available in the action isolate.
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { (registry) in
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: registry)
    }

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```